# What does Angular Acceleration signify?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

$$a_T=\alpha r$$ is the tangential acceleration and  where $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration and $r$ is the radius of the circular path.

I know how we get to this mathematically,

If $v=\omega r$ then differentiating this equation we get to the expression that I have above.

But my professor says the angular acceleration comes into picture only when I apply breaks or increase the velocity.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular speed $\omega$ is how fast your wheels are spinning. How many degrees (or radians) per second they are turning with.

Angular acceleration $\alpha$ is how fast this spinning speeds up or down. How many more or fewer degrees per second the wheel is turning with every second.

It is a direct equivalent to linear velocity $v$ and linear acceleration $a$, just with arc length, degrees, rather than actual length, metres.

Answer (score 1):

Angular acceleration $\alpha$ is the rate of change of angular velocity $\omega$ with time.  So $\omega$ must increase or decrease somehow if there is an angular acceleration, since $\omega  = \frac{v}{r}$ one way it can happen is that $v$ changes.

Presumably your professor was talking about the case where $r$ is constant.

Comment: yes....r was constant

Comment: @Orpheus Ok, yes, then it that case if $\omega$ were to change it'll be if $v$ changes, from the formula (applying the brakes decreases the velocity of the circular motion). Hope it helped.

Comment: So is the tangential acceleration is$ \frac{v^2}{r}$? and angular acceleration is radial?...this is where my confusion is!

Comment: m sorry I didn't add this to the question...should I edit the question?

Comment: angular acceleration is the change in the angular velocity with time, e.g. if it goes from 6rads/s to 12 rads/s in 2 seconds, the angular acceleration is 3 rads/s/s.  It's about how the angle changes instead of how the position of the mass changes

Comment: In which direction is angular acceleration aligned?...is it like at any point there are two acceleration components one is radial and the other is tangential and resulting acceleration is the vector sum of these two accelerations?

Comment: When talking about the mass, there are two clear directions for the acceleration, radial or tangential.  When talking about angular acceleration, the direction is not so clear - it's different - (we are no longer talking about the mass, but about the line between the axis and the mass, and how the angle between that line and a fixed line changes) Probably best to think of it just as the magnitude of the increase in angular velocity (although technically it's a vector and has a direction perpendicular to the circle)

Comment: thanks a lot @JohnHunter!